# Date matching in Swift not working code there

Tags: ios, swift

iam trying to send some string dates to one method and if its matching the date format then return true,

my input paramters look like "4325/353/53" this is fail case and success case "09/25/2020"

my methode, but this is returning fail for everything. pls help

```
func isValidDate(dateString: String) -> Bool {
        let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        if let _ = dateFormatterGet.date(from: dateString) {
            //date parsing succeeded, if you need to do additional logic, replace _ with some variable name i.e date
            return true
        } else {
            // Invalid date
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: 25 is not a month

Answer (score 1):

Your date format goes day-month-year, but your success case is month-day-year.

Either change your success case to match your date format ("25/09/2020") or change your date format to match your success case:

```
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
```